# Postman: unable to input user-defined value within URL

Tags: postman, informatica

I am trying to enter a user-defined value in the URL:

```
https://api.insideview.com/api/v1/company/{companyId}/familyTree
```

Here `{companyId}` is supposed to be user-defined.

I am unable to do so using informatica.
It is not accepting value in between.

How should I modify my settings to make this enabled?

Answer (score 1):

In Postman, user defined variable are enclosed in **double** brackets, so:

```
https://api.insideview.com/api/v1/company/{{companyId}}/familyTree
```